# NodeJS/ExpressJS : Access URL of the post request

Tags: node.js, express, url

In a project  I'm working on, I need to access the parameters of the url in the backend.
I tried this based on what I found on the internet, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
//url = "/getDocs?num=15" 

router.get("/getDocs", function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.body.num);
    res.redirect("/documents");
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

In `url` it seems you are using `query string` which can be accessed as: **`request.query.num`**

If you are passing only `params` in `url` like `getDocs/:num` value then it can be accessed as: **`request.params.num`**

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of doing this is querying the req object with the property name:

```
router.get("/getDocs", function(req,res,next){
    const name = req.query.name;
    res.redirect("/documents");
}
```

If you sending as a part of route, you can use this:

```
router.get("/getDocs/:id", function(req,res,next){
    const id = req.params.id;
    res.redirect("/documents");
}
```

For more details check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-req-query-property/).